# Как извлечь найденные регулярным выражениям подстроки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка

```
$path = '/user/5';
```

Мне нужно извлечь число 5 из нее, я могу проверить ее регулярным выражением:

```
preg_match('/\/user\/[0-9]/', $path, $matches)
```

Но в данном случае $matches будет равен $path (var_dump $matches):

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "/user/5" }
```

Как максимально быстро извлечь 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В своем выражении, вы не объявляете группировку `([0-9]+)`, нужно брать в круглые скобки, попробуйте так:

```
$path = '/user/5';

preg_match('~/user/([0-9]+)~', $path, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Как максимально быстро извлечь 5?*

Без регулярных выражений: преобразовать строку в массив, и извлечь его последний элемент:

```
$path = '/user/5';
$temp = str_split($path);

echo end($temp); // 5
```